# Account balance incorrectly calculated

Tags: java

The result of running the below code is:

```
Final account balance is: -97.0
```

But the answer should be 150.0, right? Where have I gone wrong?

```
class Account
{
  double initBalance;

  Account(double initBalance)
  {
    initBalance=this.initBalance;
  }

  double getBalance()
  {
    return initBalance;
  }

  void deposit(double amt)
  {
    initBalance=initBalance + amt;
  }

  void withdraw(double amt)
  {
    initBalance=initBalance - amt;
  }

}


class TestAccount
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Account acct=new Account(100);
    acct.deposit(50);
    System.out.println("Final account balance is: " +acct.getBalance());
  }
}
```

Comment: **what is wrong in this program** code formatting ?? :P

Comment: Using proper code formatting is the least you can do when posting a question. Since you want something from us (help), you should make it as easy as possible for us to help you. We should not have to wade through a sea of characters to understand your code.

Comment: what exactly is the error because ans should be 150.0 i get it -97.0 y?

Comment: @user1918213 your current code gives 50.0 if you change constructor than you'll get 150.0. I don't understand how you get -97.0. Are you sure it's all your code?

Comment: I do not see why you are voting to close this question. Maybe he's not familiar with object oriented programming

Comment: ok..i am just a new user i will get used to this..

Comment: i used seperate files account.java and testaccount.java i got -97.0 and dont know y but i copied the code back from here in to a singlefile as testaccount.java and and run it..i get 50.0..

Comment: @user1918213 try debug your app. It helps in most cases.

Comment: @user1918213 - *"... and dont know y but ..."*.  You obviously forgot to sacrifice a chicken before you ran the program the first time .... :-) Seriously, you need to be a LOT more careful with the way that you develop your code.  In particular, you need to make sure that you recompile everything that needs recompiling after each edit ... especially if you are running `javac` by hand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Account(double initBalance) {
   initBalance=this.initBalance;
}
```

must be

```
Account(double initBalance) {
   this.initBalance=initBalance;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not right:

```
Account(double initBalance)
{
initBalance=this.initBalance;
}
```

That should be:

```
this.initBalance = initBalance;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your constructor, try this

```
Account(double initBalance)
{
    this.initBalance = initBalance;
}
```

This is precisely the reason why method parameters should have different names than instance variables and also use of final should be favored to avoid such mistakes. If your constructor param was final, the compiler itself would have warned you. Good Practice

```
Account(final double pInitBalance)
{
    initBalance = pInitBalance;
}
```

Comment: I disagree with your last point. Having clear names makes it easier to read. After all, you won't be the only one using, reviewing the code

Comment: @AdelBoutros I never said the name shouldn't be clear; I just said that a naming convention which helps you identify a method or constructor parameter helps, look at my good practice suggestion

Comment: I still think keeping the same name is better with the use of This pointer. I am not saying you can't do it but if I read it, I will wonder why it has a "p" at the start. After all it's a subjective view :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the code of constructor. This variant is right:

```
Account(double initBalance) {
        this.initBalance = initBalance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Account
{
    public double initBalance;

    public Account(double initBalance)
    {
        this.initBalance =     initBalance;
    }

    double getBalance()
    {
        return initBalance;
    }

    void deposit(double amt)
    {
        initBalance=initBalance + amt;
    }

    void withdraw(double amt)
    {
        initBalance=initBalance - amt;
    }
}


public class TestAccount
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Account acct=new Account(100);
        //System.out.println("account balance after deposit 100 is: " +acct.getBalance());
        acct.deposit(50);
        //System.out.println("account balance after deposit 100 + 50 is: " +acct.getBalance());
        System.out.println("Final account balance is: " +acct.getBalance());
    }
}
```

This is the right code. Check it.